# Cannot connect to SQL Server using SqlClient in a desktop application

Tags: c#, sql-server

Connecting to SQL Server with a SQL username and password is no problem at all.
These scenarios work just fine:

- from C# code using SqlClient in ASP.NET / MVC
- with ssms
- with Visual Studio Connection Properties Wizard

For example, this works in an MVC project:

```
new SqlConnection("Server=DB1;Database=testdb;User Id=testuser;Password=testuser1;").Open();
```

**But** this identical code fails when run in a desktop application project. It causes the following inner exception error:

> user name or password is incorrect

(yes there is a space between user and name)

I've tried:

- making sure the protocols are right in SQL Config Manager.
- opening up ports in the firewall on client and server.
- connecting to another database to see if it's the database and not the client.
- the NuGet version of SqlClient.
- restarting the dev machine and the server.
- ensured the Browser SQL service is running.
- ensured the main SQL service is set to automatic and is running.
- SqlClient, OLEDB, and ODBC along with appropriate connection strings.
- Storing the username and password in a separate credentials object.
- Specifying Integrated Security=False in the connection string

But still, nothing.

Why can I connect to SQL Server from everything **except** from code running in a desktop .NET application? Is something along the way stripping my password out before the connection happens?

Comment: where is the desktop application running? can you run ssms from that machine?

Comment: That's really weird. Can you try putting a profiler and check [Audit Login Failed Event information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187862(v=sql.110).aspx)?

Comment: One thing I could see (likely not the issue, but ...) is : do you have a SQL Server installed on your desktop (from which you are running the app), and if so, is it possible that it would confuse the names and try to connect to your local SQL server instead of the dedicated server?

Comment: Are you running 32/64 bit? Are there differences in framework versions?

Comment: The desktop app is installed in dev machine? And where is the SQL Server? If ok, create temporary Login, User and kindly let us know domain or IP address with temporary credential so that we try connecting with our own desktop apps(like WPF).

Answer (score 0):

Let's try :

```
data source=DB1;initial catalog=testdb;persist security info=True;user id=testuser;password=testuser1;
```

User must be a SQL user.